# Problem with \newcommand and \renewcommand

Tags: math-mode, macros, bold, renewcommand

[image]I am trying to define a command called \vec{} that prints a bold and non-italic symbol in math environment.

```
\renewcommand{\vec}[1]{\mathbf{#1}}
```

usually works for me, but not in the documentclass ifacconf.
Instead,

```
\newcommand{\vect}[1]{\mathbf{#1}}
```

works here. Can someone please explain the difference to me?

Thank you! :-)

MWE:

```
\documentclass{ifacconf}
\usepackage{natbib}        % required for bibliography
%% own packages
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}

%% own commands
\renewcommand{\vec}[1]{\mathbf{#1}}
\newcommand{\vect}[1]{\mathbf{#1}}

\begin{document}
\begin{frontmatter}

\title{Title, preferably not more than 10 words}

\begin{abstract}                
Abstract of not more than 250 words.
\end{abstract}

\end{frontmatter}
\begin{verbatim}
\mathbf{A}
\end{verbatim} prints
\begin{equation}
\mathbf{A},
\end{equation}

\begin{verbatim}
\vec{A}
\end{verbatim} prints
\begin{equation}
\vec{A},
\end{equation}

\begin{verbatim}
\vect{A}
\end{verbatim} prints
\begin{equation}
\vect{A}
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

Comment: what error do you get, and where is `ifacconf.cls` ?

Comment: I do not get any error, but the result confuses me :(

Comment: Commenting out the frontmatter environment solves the problem, but is of course not a solution for me

Comment: https://www.ifac-control.org/conferences/author-guide/copy_of_ifacconf_latex.zip/view

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the problem is simple:
frontmatter overwrites your command.
Solution: Just copy your line

```
\renewcommand{\vec}[1]{\mathbf{#1}}
```

and paste it after you ended frontmatter or even inside the frontmatter environment to get your command inside this environment there.

I hope this helps!

Cheers,
Nick

Answer (score 4):

Using

https://raw.githubusercontent.com/worc4021/ifac2017/master/ifacconf.cls

The class defines a command `\undo@AMS` specifically used in `\frontmatter` that redefines `\vec` to be bold italic.

So the simplest things are either go with the flow and use bold italic, or to define your own command as you show.

Comment: I got it, thank you very much!!! :)